# Can't debug class within App_Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

When I created a class for my web app project it suggested I move the class to the App_Data folder, which I did. Only problem is now, I can debug through my backend code that's not in that folder but any classes I want to debug into, I'm not able to and the debugger will simply skip over it. I've looked all over for the reason but have found mostly `web.config` files setup incorrectly or Client framework rather than .net framework.

I have confirmed both are fine in my system, and that the project was built under Debug mode. I'm using the built in web debugger, not using IIS yet but I've tried attaching the debugger to the web service within VS08.

Below is my `web.config` relating to debugging:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Comment: Data and stuff belongs in `App_Data` - code classes belong in **`App_Code`**

Comment: Many thanks, I've moved the class out of App_Data and created a new folder App_Code and tried to debug again but it still seems to be skipping over that class within the App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set system.codedom (I'd remove that unless you have another reason for specifying the information there), but all you'll need is:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <compilation
            debug="true"
            ...
        >
        ...
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note the debug="true". Attach debugger to running process or just start up with f5.

Comment: I didn't set this codedom code, actually.  This was system generated but I have ensured that the compilation debug = true.  Debugging is working fine for any code that's not in the code-behind

Comment: What's the actual code? And you have (obvious) rebuilt/cleaned?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you do not want to place Class inside **App_Data** folder which is not meant for storing Class.

If you want to add Class to **App_Code** folder, you need to change **Build Action** to **Compile**.

[image]

Comment: I have ensured that the Build Action is set to Compile.  I have also tried moving the class outside of the folders to the root folder of the project but I'm still having the same issue